# MySQL GROUP BY return more than one row per group

Tags: mysql, group-by

Given a sample table:

```
| id | locationID |      Date_Time      | temp |
|----|------------|---------------------|------|
| 1  | L001       | 2018-09-04 11:25:00 | 52.6 |
| 2  | L002       | 2018-09-04 11:35:00 | 66.1 |
| 3  | L003       | 2018-09-04 03:30:00 | 41.2 |
| 4  | L003       | 2018-09-05 10:22:00 | 71.8 |
| 5  | L003       | 2018-09-06 14:21:00 | 63.4 |
| 6  | L003       | 2018-09-06 18:18:00 | 50.1 |
```

I would like to return the latest N number of records for each group as below:

Expected output:

```
| id | locationID |      Date_Time      | temp |
|----|------------|---------------------|------|
| 1  | L001       | 2018-09-04 11:25:00 | 52.6 |
| 2  | L002       | 2018-09-04 11:35:00 | 66.1 |
| 4  | L003       | 2018-09-05 10:22:00 | 71.8 |
| 5  | L003       | 2018-09-06 14:21:00 | 63.4 |
| 6  | L003       | 2018-09-06 18:18:00 | 50.1 |
```

I have this query but it only returns the latest row for each group? I would like to return more than one row (N number of rows) for each group?

```
SELECT *
FROM HealthStatus
WHERE Date_Time IN (
    SELECT MAX(Date_Time)
    FROM HealthStatus
    GROUP BY LocationID
)
```

Would really appreciate some help on how I can achieve my desired output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why rowno 3 is missing - what is the logic as it is in different date, for location 3 how many row is your desired and why

Comment: @fa06: Presumably because N=3

Comment: This *is* something of a frequently asked question

Comment: @fa06 The second table is the output I would like to achieve. As mentioned, I would like to return more than a row for each group (i.e 3 rows). The query I mentioned above will only give me row 1,2 and 6.

Comment: @seankoh from your question it seems to me that 3 & 4 should not be result set cause it's different than max date - am i right? I want to make sure why 4 is in your expected output?

Comment: @fa06 You mean 4 and 5? Yes, therefore I would like to how how I can modify my query - instead of using max date, is there any way that I can get the latest N rows for each group?

Comment: Which MySQL? The new 8.0 has window functions which makes this much much much easier.

Comment: @Amadan MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*is there any way that I can get the latest N rows for each group?*

Prior to the availability of row_number() you can use variables to mimic that function

```
SELECT
*
FROM (
    SELECT
          @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=locationID,@row_num+1,1)AS RowNumber
        , id , locationID , Date_Time,temp
        , @prev_value := locationID
    FROM HealthStatus
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
    ORDER BY
          locationID , Date_Time DESC
    ) derived
WHERE RowNumber < 4
```

Comment: Oh, nice! I keep forgetting about variables, but they're really powerful.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to MySQL 8.0, then this would solve it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY locationID ORDER BY Date_Time DESC) AS r
  FROM HealthStatus
) T
WHERE r <= 3;
```

On 5.7... I can't think of a way. :(

Comment: Nevertheless, they do exist.